# angular calendar how to change language

Tags: angular

I'm working with [angular calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/i18n), by default the language is english, i want to change it to spanish.

My issue is that the documentation is poor, even the stackblitz example only works with french, if i try with spanish code (es), or any other language code, the calendar doesn't show nothing at all.

How i can change the names of the days & months properly with angular calendar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The repo's [changelog](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/blob/74f74b75b61d420215efde04777b9f8ddcb05922/CHANGELOG.md#0230-2018-01-02) explains that if you want to use a "locale other than english you will need to import the appropriate locale data".

In this case:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';

registerLocaleData(localeEs);
```

See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6su8pq).

Comment: also make sure to add `[locale]="locale"` in your `<mwl-calendar-day-view>`, `<mwl-calendar-week-view>`,`<mwl-calendar-month-view>`  tags.
and in your component add `locale: string = "es";`.

Comment: Day saver, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adicional the import, you need to do the next for change the month language

`<div class="title">
   {{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'Es' }}
 </div>`

and to change the week language, add the property locale="es" in `<mwl-calendar-month-view>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/en-au'; //English language

import frLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/fr'; //French language

//if you want to change the calendar in english or french langages or any langage you want,
//just import the langage of the local then follow this example

locale:this.translate.getBrowserLang() == 'fr' ? frLocale : esLocale,
```